# Calculating integer log base 2 for a float in Java

Tags: java

How can I find log base 2, rounded down (as an integer), for a float in Java?

Is there a fast way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can calculate this using Java's standard math library, using the change of base rule for logarithms:

```
public static final int log2(float f)
{
    return (int)Math.floor(Math.log(f)/Math.log(2.0));
}
```

Or you can exploit the fact that this information is stored explicitly within an IEEE 754 float:

[image: Taken from en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Float_example.svg]

The exponent actually contains precisely the answer you're looking for, all you have to do is bit shift it all the way to the right and subtract 127 from it. Of course, some floating point values have an exponent of -127 (represented as zero). These are called *subnormal* values, and extracting their logarithm is a bit tricky. Here it is found using a lookup table:

```
private static final int[] logTable = new int[256];

static
{
    logTable[0] = logTable[1] = 0;
    for (int i=2; i<256; i++) logTable[i] = 1 + logTable[i/2];
    logTable[0] = -1;
}

public static final int log2(float f)
{
    int x = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
    int c = x >> 23;

    if (c != 0) return c - 127; //Compute directly from exponent.
    else //Subnormal, must compute from mantissa.
    {
        int t = x >> 16;
        if (t != 0) return logTable[t] - 133;
        else return (x >> 8 != 0) ? logTable[t] - 141 : logTable[x] - 149;
    }
}
```

This solution, adapted from [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogFloat), is quite a bit faster than the previous one. Both of these methods will have undefined results for negative or infinite values, zero, and NaN--as they should, unless you're working in the complex space.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is a `Math.getExponent(float)` method that will do the first part (getting the exponent from the float) for you.